# Failed pushing to Github Container Registry

Tags: github, github-actions, docker-push

I am using GitHub workflows to push a small package to a private GH container registry. Yesterday most of my workflows went through, but suddenly they stop working. I am not aware of any recent setting changes.

I am using `{{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN}}` with Workflow write permissions enabled.

[image]

I replaced my actual organization name with `test-user` for privacy reasons.

```
buildx failed with: ERROR: failed to solve: failed to push test-user/bar:1.8.2:
    failed to authorize: failed to fetch oauth token: unexpected status: 401 Unauthorized
```

This is an extract of my workflow file:

```yaml
      - name: Login to Docker registry
        uses: docker/login-action@v2
        with:
          registry: ghcr.io
          username: ${{ github.repository_owner }}
          password: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}

... 

      - name: Build and push
        uses: docker/build-push-action@v4
        with:
          context: .
          push: true
          tags: ${{ steps.meta.outputs.tags }}
          labels: ${{ steps.meta.outputs.labels }}
```

Any idea what could trigger the 401?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are only pushing images with the `ghcr.io/` prefix in the name. Otherwise, it will try to push to docker hub and fail if you haven't used the login action to login to docker hub.

Comment: here is the docs https://docs.docker.com/build/ci/github-actions/manage-tags-labels/